# How can I store a variable in a list number?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a piece of code which uses a counter to move through a list but the problem is that when I do `counter+1` it does not store in the variable counter.

code:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
counter = 0
b = list[counter]+list[counter+1]
print(counter)
```

I expect this to return 1 since I added 1 to the counter but instead it returns 0 as if i had not add anything.

Comment: The expression `counter + 1` does not assign or reassign a value. Unfortunately python does not have  `++` operator, so change the value you will need to add a 'counter += 1` to your code.

Comment: Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: Also please try not using Python builtin `list` as variable name.

Comment: @Jigsaw without using a global variable and an increment method or wrapper object, unfortunately not, and using either of the methods I mentioned would require more code to accomplish the same thing and would probably be much less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As joshmeranda said, `counter + 1` does not change the `counter` variable.

You'd probably have to separately increment the `counter` variable, like:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
counter = 0
b = list[counter]+list[counter+1]
counter += 1 #variable += 1 is syntastic sugar for variable = variable + 1
print(counter)
```